# can laravel artisan show how many migrations are ready to be installed?

Tags: php, laravel

Can laravel artisan show how many migrations are ready to be installed?

Something like:

```
php artisan migrate:just_show_not_performed_migrations
```

Comment: just use `php artisan migrate --pretend`

Comment: Thanks. Good to know, it is a cool feature, but it only shows the first migration in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `php artisan migrate:status`. It will output all migrations, with a green 'Y' next to the ones who have been migrated and a red 'N' next to the ones who have not.